# Binance api HMAC SHA256 using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sha256, hmac, binance

I am trying to connect to Binance api from my Rails application. But every time I am getting `401 unauthorized` error message from Binance. Below is my code.

```
  class Binance
    END_POINT = 'https://api.binance.com'.freeze
    KEY = 'my-binance-key'
    SECRET = 'my-binance-secret'

    def self.account_info
       url = "#{END_POINT}/api/v3/account"
       query_string = "timestamp=#{DateTime.now.strftime('%Q')}"
       digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256')
       signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, SECRET, query_string)
       url = "#{END_POINT}/api/v3/account?#{query_string}&signature=#{signature}"
       response = RestClient.get(url, headers: { 'X-MBX-APIKEY': KEY })
    end
  end
```

Here is a link from Binance api with example:

https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#signed-endpoint-examples-for-post-apiv3order

Comment: Getting a 401 from what, your app or the external API?

Comment: @tadman from external API (Binance)

Comment: @r33b00t the sample in github curl is a POST request, you use get

Comment: @darkash ya in example they are using `order` endpoint which required post. But for `account_info` it requires get.

Comment: Hope this is not too late, but https://github.com/binance/binance-connector-ruby has the code of signature, which maybe helpful.